# Update Table with a "Select query" with a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-update

I want to achieve the following:

**Current State of table (my_table)**

```
 id        totalX          totalY          totalZ               
 --------- --------------  --------------  --------------       
         9             34              334             0      
        10              6               56             0      
        11             21              251             0      
        12              3               93             0
```

**Query result of (my_table2)**

```
select id,count(*) as total FROM my_table2 WHERE column_2 = 1 GROUP BY id

 id        total               
 --------- --------------       
         9            500      
        10            600      
        11            700      
        12            800
```

**Expected State of table (my_table)**

```
 id        totalX          totalY          totalZ               
 --------- --------------  --------------  --------------       
         9             34              334             500      
        10              6               56             600      
        11             21              251             700      
        12              3               93             800
```

Can this be done in ONE update query ? I am looking for Sybase ASE 12.5 on a RHEL 5.0

**EDIT:** I coudn't find the solution for Sybase, but the current answer to the question works on MS SQL Server..

Comment: Is there any field joining my_table and my_table2?  It looks like the joining field is arbitrary.

Comment: Joining Field is "id" .. The problem is that the query of my_table2 requires a group by.

Comment: NVM, I misread the second query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
   update 
          my_table 
   set 
      my_table.totalZ = t.total 
   FROM
    my_table mt
    INNER JOIN 
       (select id,count(*) as total 
       FROM my_table2 
      WHERE column_2 = 1 GROUP BY id) t
   on mt.id  = t.id
```

**UPDATE** In MS SQL Server this is what you would do. The OP noted this doesn't work in Sybase.

Comment: This produces error:  Msg 11762, Level 15, State 1:
Server 'DEVDB1', Line 1:
You cannot use a derived table in the FROM clause of an UPDATE or DELETE statement

Comment: @Stewie Sorry about that. I should have included in my answer that I hadn't checked Sybase but works in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Thats what I guessed. It should work with MySQL too .. I guess Sybase is just being a Bi**h

Comment: Does sybase have temp tables? PUt the results of the query in a temp table and then join to that inthe update.

Comment: @HLGEM That wouldn't be one query would it.

Comment: Sybase doens't allow derived tables with `group by` in `update` or `delete` statements. As @HLGEM stated, you can use temp tables to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

something like this should do the trick

```
update my_table
set my_table.totalZ = (select count(*) from my_table2 where my_table.id = my_table2.id and my_table2.column_2 = 1);
```

Comment: I figured there was no way this would work, but it did.  A very late thank you.

Comment: this wont work in sybase as it does not allow derived tables in update from clauses

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Sybase supports joins with updates:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20023_1251/html/optimizer/optimizer133.htm

Answer (score 0):

The best and more reliable way is to use MERGE.

```
MERGE INTO my_table
USING (select id,count(*) as total FROM my_table2 WHERE column_2 = 1 GROUP BY id) t2
ON (my_table.id=t2.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET totalZ = t2.total
```

Reference : http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/commands89.htm